# How can I make my jquery fullcalendar plugin avoid accepting dayclick on overlap=false

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I would like to ask for your support. I need to read the property `overlap` in the JSON to do something different if the day was marked as not available.

I have this JSON for the event:

```
{
  start: '2015-02-06',
  end: '2015-02-09',
  overlap: false,
  rendering: 'background',
  color: '#ff9f89'
}
```

and the `dayClick` function:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
   alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
   alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
   alert('Current view: ' + view.name);
}
```

Results:

[image: Results]

:Update:

This is my Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/SqY9W1QTmJIzycHllOqG

I want to recognize the red zone using "dayClick event" as no clickable.

Comment: Can you please provide a little more context with your ask. I see the function, but with the `alert` it is unclear the goal, or relevance of the snippet, especially how it relates to the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this would be to keep the date range in a variable that is accessable to the event `dayClick` callback, then check the date that is passed to `dayClick` like so:

```
if ( date.isBetween(jsonEventVar.start, jsonEventVar.end) ) {
    alert('no clicking here');
} else {
    alert('you can click here');
}
```